# How to rewrite numbers written in the string type to the numbers?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, mathematical-optimization, numerics, string-manipulation

I have a list with string type characters:

```
{"5\.009\.00.\.004\.005\.007\.005\.008\.005\.00", \
"\.005\.009\.00.\.003\.007\.009\.004\.008\.005\.00", "\.001\.00", "\
\.000"}
```

Is it possible to change string symbols to the corresponding numbers?

I would like to get the following list:

```
{59.457585, 59.379485, 1, 0}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem are the `\.00` characters interspersed with useful characters. `\.00` is the [NULL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) and usually does not occur in "sane" strings (it is often used as a string terminator).

My first suggestion would be to eliminate the NULL characters at the source.

If you cannot do that, then just delete them:

```
s = {"5\.009\.00.\.004\.005\.007\.005\.008\.005\.00",
     "\.005\.009\.00.\.003\.007\.009\.004\.008\.005\.00",
     "\.001\.00",
     "\.000"};

ToExpression@StringDelete[s, "\.00"]
(*    {59.457585`, 59.379485`, 1, 0}    *)
```